# Find all intersections of all sets of ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

I'm looking for an efficient way to find all the intersections between sets of timestamp ranges. It needs to work with PostgreSQL 9.2.

Let's say the ranges represent the times when a person is available to meet. Each person may have one or more ranges of times when they are available. I want to find *all* the time periods when a meeting can take place (ie. during which all people are available).

This is what I've got so far. It seems to work, but I don't think it's very efficient, since it considers one person's availability at a time.

```
WITH RECURSIVE td AS
(
    -- Test data. Returns:
    -- ["2014-01-20 00:00:00","2014-01-31 00:00:00")
    -- ["2014-02-01 00:00:00","2014-02-20 00:00:00")
    -- ["2014-04-15 00:00:00","2014-04-20 00:00:00")
    SELECT 1 AS entity_id, '2014-01-01'::timestamp AS begin_time, '2014-01-31'::timestamp AS end_time
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-28'
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-04-01', '2014-04-30'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-01-15', '2014-02-20'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-04-15', '2014-05-05'
    UNION SELECT 3, '2014-01-20', '2014-04-20'
)
, ranges AS
(
    -- Convert to tsrange type
    SELECT entity_id, tsrange(begin_time, end_time) AS the_range
    FROM td
)
, min_max AS
(
    SELECT MIN(entity_id), MAX(entity_id)
    FROM td
)
, inter AS
(
    -- Ranges for the lowest ID
    SELECT entity_id AS last_id, the_range
    FROM ranges r
    WHERE r.entity_id = (SELECT min FROM min_max)

    UNION ALL

    -- Iteratively intersect with ranges for the next higher ID
    SELECT entity_id, r.the_range * i.the_range
    FROM ranges r
    JOIN inter i ON r.the_range && i.the_range
    WHERE r.entity_id > i.last_id
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM ranges r2
            WHERE r2.entity_id < r.entity_id AND r2.entity_id > i.last_id
        )
)
-- Take the final set of intersections
SELECT *
FROM inter
WHERE last_id = (SELECT max FROM min_max)
ORDER BY the_range;
```

Comment: Unrelated: supplying "static data" can be done shorter without using  `select` and `union` by using a `values` clause: `values (1, '2014-01-01'::timestamp, '2014-01-31'::timestamp), (2, ...)` and define the column names in the CTE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created the `tsrange_interception_agg` aggregate

```
create function tsrange_interception (
    internal_state tsrange, next_data_values tsrange
) returns tsrange as $$
    select internal_state * next_data_values;
$$ language sql;

create aggregate tsrange_interception_agg (tsrange) (
    sfunc = tsrange_interception,
    stype = tsrange,
    initcond = $$[-infinity, infinity]$$
);
```

Then this query

```
with td (id, begin_time, end_time) as
(
    values
    (1, '2014-01-01'::timestamp, '2014-01-31'::timestamp),
    (1, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-28'),
    (1, '2014-04-01', '2014-04-30'),
    (2, '2014-01-15', '2014-02-20'),
    (2, '2014-04-15', '2014-05-05'),
    (3, '2014-01-20', '2014-04-20')
), ranges as (
    select
        id,
        row_number() over(partition by id) as rn,
        tsrange(begin_time, end_time) as tr
    from td
), cr as (
    select r0.tr tr0, r1.tr as tr1
    from ranges r0 cross join ranges r1
    where
        r0.id < r1.id and
        r0.tr && r1.tr and
        r0.id = (select min(id) from td)
)
select tr0 * tsrange_interception_agg(tr1) as interseptions
from cr
group by tr0
having count(*) = (select count(distinct id) from td) - 1
;
                 interseptions                 
-----------------------------------------------
 ["2014-02-01 00:00:00","2014-02-20 00:00:00")
 ["2014-01-20 00:00:00","2014-01-31 00:00:00")
 ["2014-04-15 00:00:00","2014-04-20 00:00:00")
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this aggregate idea to solve my original problem, which turned out more complex than this, so I'm marking this accepted. (I couldn't just distil it down to a set of tsranges, but still used an aggregate, just a more complex one.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of entities you want to cross reference, you can use a cross join for each of them, and build the intersection (using the `*` operator on ranges).

Using a cross join like this is probably less efficient, though. The following example has more to do with explaining the more complex example below.

```
WITH td AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS entity_id, '2014-01-01'::timestamp AS begin_time, '2014-01-31'::timestamp AS end_time
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-28'
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-04-01', '2014-04-30'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-01-15', '2014-02-20'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-04-15', '2014-05-05'
    UNION SELECT 4, '2014-01-20', '2014-04-20'
)
,ranges AS
(
    -- Convert to tsrange type
    SELECT entity_id, tsrange(begin_time, end_time) AS the_range
    FROM td
)
SELECT r1.the_range * r2.the_range * r3.the_range AS r
FROM ranges r1
CROSS JOIN ranges r2
CROSS JOIN ranges r3
WHERE r1.entity_id=1 AND r2.entity_id=2 AND r3.entity_id=4
  AND NOT isempty(r1.the_range * r2.the_range * r3.the_range)
ORDER BY r
```

In this case a multiple cross join is probably less efficient because you don't actually need to have all the possible combinations of every range in reality, since `isempty(r1.the_range * r2.the_range)` is enough to make `isempty(r1.the_range * r2.the_range * r3.the_range)` true.

I don't think you can avoid going through each person's availability at time, since you want them all to be meet anyway.

What may help is to build the set of intersections incrementally, by cross joining each person's availability to the previous subset you've calculated using another recursive CTE (`intersections` in the example below). You then build the intersections incrementally and get rid of the empty ranges, both stored arrays:

```
WITH RECURSIVE td AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS entity_id, '2014-01-01'::timestamp AS begin_time, '2014-01-31'::timestamp AS end_time
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-28'
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-04-01', '2014-04-30'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-01-15', '2014-02-20'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-04-15', '2014-05-05'
    UNION SELECT 4, '2014-01-20', '2014-04-20'
)
,ranges AS
(
    -- Convert to tsrange type
    SELECT entity_id, tsrange(begin_time, end_time) AS the_range
    FROM td
)
,ranges_arrays AS (
    -- Prepare an array of all possible intervals per entity
    SELECT entity_id, array_agg(the_range) AS ranges_arr
    FROM ranges
       GROUP BY entity_id
)
,numbered_ranges_arrays AS (
    -- We'll join using pos+1 next, so we want continuous integers
    -- I've changed the example entity_id from 3 to 4 to demonstrate this.
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS pos, entity_id, ranges_arr
    FROM ranges_arrays
)
,intersections (pos, subranges) AS (
    -- We start off with the infinite range.
    SELECT 0::bigint, ARRAY['[,)'::tsrange]
    UNION ALL
    -- Then, we unnest the previous intermediate result,
    -- cross join it against the array of ranges from the
    -- next row in numbered_ranges_arrays (joined via pos+1).
    -- We take the intersection and remove the empty array.
    SELECT r.pos,
           ARRAY(SELECT x * y FROM unnest(r.ranges_arr) x CROSS JOIN unnest(i.subranges) y WHERE NOT isempty(x * y))
    FROM numbered_ranges_arrays r
        INNER JOIN intersections i ON r.pos=i.pos+1
)
,last_intersections AS (
    -- We just really want the result from the last operation (with the max pos).
    SELECT subranges FROM intersections ORDER BY pos DESC LIMIT 1
)
SELECT unnest(subranges) r FROM last_intersections ORDER BY r
```

I'm not sure whether this is likely to perform better, unfortunately. You'd probably need a larger dataset to have meaningful benchmarks.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, though the performance was similar to my original query. The aggregate solution ended up being a bit faster.

Comment: @EM Good to know. Just out of curiosity, if you have a dataset to test this nearby, could you try to see if changing `WHERE NOT isempty(x * y)` into `WHERE x && y` in the `CROSS JOIN` in my query improves the performance?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I wrote and tested this in TSQL but it should run or at least be close enough for you to translate back, it's all fairly vanilla constructs. <del>Except maybe the between, but that can be broken into a < clause and a > clause.</del> (thanks @Horse)

```
WITH cteSched AS ( --Schedule for everyone
    -- Test data. Returns:
    -- ["2014-01-20 00:00:00","2014-01-31 00:00:00")
    -- ["2014-02-01 00:00:00","2014-02-20 00:00:00")
    -- ["2014-04-15 00:00:00","2014-04-20 00:00:00")
    SELECT 1 AS entity_id, '2014-01-01' AS begin_time, '2014-01-31' AS end_time
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-02-01', '2014-02-28'
    UNION SELECT 1, '2014-04-01', '2014-04-30'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-01-15', '2014-02-20'
    UNION SELECT 2, '2014-04-15', '2014-05-05'
    UNION SELECT 3, '2014-01-20', '2014-04-20'
), cteReq as (  --List of people to schedule (or is everyone in Sched required? Not clear, doesn't hurt)
    SELECT 1 as entity_id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
), cteBegins as (
    SELECT distinct begin_time FROM cteSched as T 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT entity_id FROM cteReq as R 
                      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cteSched as X 
                                        WHERE X.entity_id = R.entity_id 
                                            AND T.begin_time BETWEEN X.begin_time AND X.end_time ))
) SELECT B.begin_time, MIN(S.end_time ) as end_time  
  FROM cteBegins as B cross join cteSched as S 
  WHERE B.begin_time between S.begin_time and S.end_time 
  GROUP BY B.begin_time
-- NOTE: This assume users do not have schedules that overlap with themselves! That is, nothing like
-- John is available 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-15 and 2014-01-10 to 2014-01-20.
```

EDIT: Add output from above (when executed on SQL-Server 2008R2)
    begin_time  end_time
    2014-01-20  2014-01-31
    2014-02-01  2014-02-20
    2014-04-15  2014-04-20

Comment: `between` is standard SQL that is supported by every DBMS.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get this to work (on my original data), but thank you anyway for an alternative approach.

Comment: @E-M what didn't work? Did you get an error? Was the output different?