# Get all possible intersections of multiple time ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range

I am trying to solve a similar problem to this one [Find all intersections of all sets of ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960719/find-all-intersections-of-all-sets-of-ranges-in-postgresql)

The difference is that in this thread it fetches the ranges where *all* the ranges overlap, while in my use case I all possible overlaps:

Consider 4 ranges such as

```
[2018-01-01, 2018-01-15]
[2018-01-01, 2018-01-02]
[2018-01-07, 2018-01-20]
[2018-01-12, 2018-01-30]
```

creating a timeline like this

```
 A [==============]
 B [=]
 C     [=============]
 D          [===============]
```

I want to fetch all the overlaps happening, so:

```
{ entities: [A, B], period: [2018-01-01, 2018-01-02] }
{ entities: [A, C], period: [2018-01-07, 2018-01-11] }
{ entities: [A, C, D], period: [2018-01-12, 2018-01-15] }
{ entities: [C, D], period: [2018-01-15, 2018-01-20] }
```

One other thing, in the result I need the most possible overlaps in the same group, which explains why there's no `A, D` overlap.
I already got `A, C, D` in the same period and there's no period with only `A, D` overlapping, while there is one for `A, C` for instance.

I managed to make the query from the other thread work with my setup / tables, but I'm not sure to understand all of it, especially what part does the "where all ranges overlap".

Thanks.

Comment: Why is `A, D` excluded from your expected output? I don't understand why `A, D` is different from `A, C`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Because there is no part of the overlap where only `A, D` are overlapping, there's always `C` at the same time and I'll always need them grouped by the most entities present.
I'll try to be clearer in the question, I didn't think of this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets a little ugly since it makes use of both Recursive CTEs as well as daterange and Postgres Range functions, but I think it's gets you in the ballpark:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE dr (id CHAR(1), range daterange);

INSERT INTO dr VALUES
    ('A', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-15'),
    ('B', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-02'),
    ('C', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-20'),
    ('D', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-30');

WITH RECURSIVE recRange AS
(
    SELECT id,
        range,
        CAST(id as varchar(100)) as path,
        1 as depth
    FROM drrange
    UNION ALL
    SELECT drrange.id,
        drrange.range * recRange.range,
        CAST(recrange.path || ',' || drrange.id AS VARCHAR(100)),
        recRange.depth + 1
    FROM recRange INNER JOIN drrange ON
            recRange.range && drrange.range 
            AND recRange.id < drrange.id                
    --Prevent cycling (which shouldn't happen with that join)
    WHERE depth < 20
),
drrange AS
(
    SELECT 
        id,
        daterange(from_date, to_date + 1) as range
    FROM dr
)
SELECT path as entities, range as period FROM recRange t1
WHERE depth > 1
    --  Keep the range only if it is NOT contained by
    --+ any other range that has a deeper depth then it   
    --+ and has the same ending id (id). This isn't the
    --+ best logic and could make false positives, but...
    --+ it's in the ballpark           
    AND NOT range <@ ANY(SELECT range FROM recRange WHERE depth > 1 AND depth > t1.depth AND id = t1.id);
```

```
 entities |         period
----------+-------------------------
 A,B      | [2018-01-01,2018-01-03)
 A,C      | [2018-01-07,2018-01-16)
 C,D      | [2018-01-12,2018-01-21)
 A,C,D    | [2018-01-12,2018-01-16)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it does seem to fit pretty well my problem! I am curious about how could a false positive happen though?

Comment: You might be right that their won't be. I would be cautious though and run it with and without that last bit of the WHERE to see what drops out with your live data to be sure. So many overlapping periods that are being normalized here it's tough to think through all of the potential scenarios.

Comment: This last bit definitely helps, I'll play around with it but I think I can mark this as the solution, thanks again!